# lifting up 3 level component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to do a toggle for the search bar. When I clicked the searchIcon, the searchBar will show or hide. However, i need to lifting up 3 level parent and child. How can I pass the onClick to do the toggle?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activities: activities,
            filteredActivities: activities,
        };
        this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

    filterActivity = searchText => {
        //
    }

    handleSearchChange = inputValue => {
        //
    };

    render() {
        const filteredActivities = this.props.filteredActivities;
        return(
            <div className="notificationsFrame">
                <div className="panel">
                    <Header name={this.props.name} />
                    <SearchBar inputChanged={this.handleSearchChange} />
                    <Content activities={this.state.filteredActivities} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <MenuIcon />
                <Title name={this.props.name} />
                <SearchIcon />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SearchIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="fa fa-search searchIcon" onClick={}></div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={this.props.onClick}
```

or

```
{...props}
```

---

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleSearchChange = inputValue => {
    console.log("test");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="notificationsFrame">
        <div className="panel">
          <Header name={this.props.name} onClick={this.handleSearchChange} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <SearchIcon onClick={this.props.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SearchIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fa fa-search searchIcon" {...this.props}>
        XXX
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]